# Microsoft Remote Desktop: Screen Zoomed In

Tags: remote-desktop

I'm currently connected to my remote desktop on my MacBook Air and although the system itself is working perfectly, it seems to be zoomed in: if I want to access the task bar, I need to scroll down, if I want to get to the close button in the top right I need to scroll up and across! This seems to be the opposite of a lot of problems that I've seen on here.

I've adjusted the resolution to a variety of different ones; I've tried manually zooming out but that didn't work, and I can't find any settings to change this. Any ideas would be massively appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

In Display Prefs for that connection, set to 'Fit session to window' & optionally 'Optimise for Retina displays'.

[image]